# How do I change mouse cursor to pointer on mouseover, and back to default in cytoscape.js and React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cytoscape.js

may I please know how do I change my mouse cursor to the pointer on mouseover, and back to the default in cytoscape.js and React.js?

Below is my code, which doesn't work. I've removed the parts which aren't relevant to the question

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import CytoscapeComponent from 'react-cytoscapejs';
import Cytoscape from 'cytoscape';

const Network = (props) => {

  let [ext_cy, setCy] = useState(null);
  const [my_cursor, setCursor] = useState('default');

          <CytoscapeComponent 
              elements={props.elements} 
              style={ {  
                height: sizeHeight + 'px',
                cursor: my_cursor
              } } 
              cy={cy => {
                cy.on('add', 'node', _evt => {
                    cy.layout(layout).run()
                    cy.fit()
                    setCy(cy)
                })
                cy.on('mouseover', 'node', changeCursor('pointer'));
                cy.on('mouseout', 'node', changeCursor('default'));
              }}
              stylesheet={stylesheet}
              layout={layout} 
              pan={ { x: x, y: 80 } }
              zoom={0.8}
              minZoom={0.5}
              maxZoom={2}
              />
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to use external styles? Because then you could just extract the styles, give you components a class and use :hover

Comment: How do I do that exactly? Sorry I'm quite new to react and cytoscape.js

Comment: create a new styles.css file (or even better styles.scss) and then import them (i think). Otherwise add a new <link>-Tag to your html file where you render your stuff. With that you have global styles. Then you can give your component a className and reference it in your Stylesheet. Basic web development

Comment: @JonathanNg Did you try change this part of your code ```cy.on('mouseover', 'node', changeCursor('pointer'));``` on something like this: ```cy.on('mouseover', 'node', function () {
            $("body").css({cursor: "pointer"});
        })```